# Java Swing Timer Loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, timer

imagine an array of numbers. Specific number-specific button, which has to blink. I have to go through the array.  Now swing timer blinks one button ok, but if I try to put `for(int I=0;i<array.length;i++)` loop to go to next button - Timer does not do it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.  Here is the code I have now:

```
Timer startGame = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        int colorPlay = 1;//which sqaure to blink
        int blinkingState = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (blinkingState < 2) {
                int i = blinkingState % 2;
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        if (colorPlay == 1) {
                            greenButton.setBackground(Color.green);
                        } else if (colorPlay == 2) {
                            redButton.setBackground(Color.red);
                        } else if (colorPlay == 3) {
                            blueButton.setBackground(Color.blue);
                        } else if (colorPlay == 4) {
                            yellowButton.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (colorPlay == 1) {
                            greenButton.setBackground(lightGreen);
                        } else if (colorPlay == 2) {
                            redButton.setBackground(lightRed);

                        } else if (colorPlay == 3) {
                            blueButton.setBackground(lightBlue);
                        } else if (colorPlay == 4) {
                            yellowButton.setBackground(lightYellow);
                        }
                        break;
                }//switch ends
                blinkingState++;
            }//if blinking<2 ends
        }//actionPerformed ends
    });//timer ends
```

Comment: Is `for(int I=0;i<array.length;i++)` free of typos? In that case you'd have both upper and lowercase i variables, and the loop does not modify the one you probably use as the button indices. (Also, since you're using arrays, using [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) would be more readable).

Comment: yes, it is free of typos. Only if I put for(.......) loop it gives the error:  "illegal start of type. Cannot find symbol class i..."  I tried to declare int i in constructor - no use.  Thanks for an attempt to help

Comment: It would be easier to tell what the error is the loops if you showed what you actually wrote. But, in any case, if the loop above is really what you tried: you apparently intend to use loop index `I`, but actually modify `i`. So assuming you use `I` as an array index, it stays `0`, since it's never modified => only the first button is affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems faulty. What you want is:

- Blink green light
- Wait
- Blink red light
- Wait
- Blink yellow light

Where a blink is

- Set regular background colour
- Wait
- Set light background colour

This means you are probably better off with two `Timer` instances.

```
Timer lightTimer = new Timer( 2000, new ActionListener(){
  private int lightCounter = 0;
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    switch( lightCounter ){
      case ...:
      final JButton lightButton = ...;
      lightButton.setBackground( regularColour );
      Timer blinkingTimer = new Timer( 1000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          lightButton.setColor( lightColour );
        }
      }
      blinkingTimer.setRepeats( false );
      blinkingTimer.start();
    }
    lightCounter++;
    if ( lightCounter == numberOfLights ){
      ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
    }
  }
} );
lightTimer.setRepeats( true );
lightTimer.start();
```

Something along the lines of the above code should do it. Note how:

- I use a second timer to switch the blinking light back to its previous state (the `BlinkingTimer` variable)
- The `BlinkingTimer` uses `setRepeats( false )` as it only needs to be triggered once
- The `LightTimer` uses `setRepeats( true )` as it needs to execute multiple times, and turns itself off once it let all lights blink

Comment: Robin, thank you for the reply.  Only in my case lightCounter suppose to go through the array list and depending which number is there - blink that button, then when that is finished - go to next blink, etc.   If I put Timer in a loop - it brings only the last blink.  I am not allowed to use threads

Comment: @user3438186 That is exactly what my code is doing. I didn't access the array, but the line `final JButton lightButton = ...;` is supposed to retrieve the correct button from the array. The code I posted was an illustration but not a full solution (just like I only added one case in the switch), but it should be trivial to complete it. _I am not allowed to use threads_ Euhm, even a Swing `Timer` uses a background thread, so you are using multiple threads

Comment: Robin!  Thanks for the code, after i have posted my comment to you i went through your sample again and figure it out exactly the way you helped - added cases and got the value for LightCounter from an Array List.   Phew, can't tell you how much it helped me....